# How can I create dataframes with names based on filenames in a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to create a function that loops through the files in my directory, creates multiple data frames with names based on filenames and writes newly created data frames to the .csv. However, the solution I created works only for the last file in a directory not for all of them. Could anyone point out my mistake?

```
 ##Peak annotation function for all the files in the directory 
 ##Loading required libraries 
 library(GenomicFeatures)
 library(GenomicRanges)
 library(AnnotationDbi)
 library(ChIPseeker)
 ##Making some annotations 
 hg38_TxDB <- makeTxDbFromGFF("/Users/dari_obukhova/data/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf")
 saveDb(hg38_TxDB, file = "/Users/dari_obukhova/data/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg38/Annotation/TxDB.sqlite")
 hg38_Annotation <- loadDb("/Users/dari_obukhova/data/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg38/Annotation/TxDB.sqlite")

 ##Function to use for all the files in the directory 
 all_peaks_files <- list.files(pattern = ".xls", full.names = T)
 for (file in all_peaks_files) {
      peak_list <- list()
      peaks_df <- read.delim(fileName, comment.char = "#")
      peaks_gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(peaks_df, keep.extra.columns = T)
      annotated_peaks_df <- as.data.frame(annotatePeak(peaks_gr, TxDb = hg38_Annotation))
      peak_list[[(length(peak_list) + 1)]] <- annotated_peaks_df
  }
  peak_list
```

However, the returned list has only one element (the list file in all_peaks_files). Moreover, I am not sure how to rename every df I create based on each specific filename. I would appreciate any suggestions! <3

Comment: Since you re-create a blank `peak_list` at the beginning of each loop, you are only saving the last result. The first line in the loop needs to be outside the loop. Fix that and then try the loop with a single file to make sure things are working properly.

Comment: Right! I was so unattentive not to notice this silly mistake.. Thanks so much for pointing this out. Could you also recommend how I should rename each df based on the filename?

Comment: Look into `assign`.

Comment: Since the data frames are stored in a list, you could just use `names(peak_list) <- all_peaks_files`. Or you could first process the names to remove the path , e.g. `basename(fname)` and extension, `gsub(".xls", "", fname)`.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody, thanks for the nice suggestions. I was able to modify my code into a working one. Here is my modified code.

```html
##Function to annotate some files with peaks generated by CHIPSeq

##Loading necessary libraries 
library(GenomicFeatures)
library(GenomicRanges)
library(AnnotationDbi)
library(ChIPseeker)

##Making some annotations of a used genome 
hESCpeaks_df <- read.delim("H3K27ac_hESC_peaks.xls", comment.char = "#")
hg38_TxDB <- makeTxDbFromGFF("/Users/dari_obukhova/data/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg38/Annotation/Genes/genes.gtf")
saveDb(hg38_TxDB, file = "/Users/dari_obukhova/data/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg38/Annotation/TxDB.sqlite")
hg38_Annotation <- loadDb("/Users/dari_obukhova/data/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg38/Annotation/TxDB.sqlite")

##Annotating all files in the directory 
all_peaks_files <- list.files(pattern = ".xls" )  ##choosing all the files with .xls extension from the working directory
peak_list <- list() ##Empty list for files to be added in 

for (file in all_peaks_files) {
  
  peaks_df <- read.delim(file, comment.char = "#")
  peaks_gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(assign(file, peaks_df), keep.extra.columns = T)
  annotated_peaks_df <- as.data.frame(annotatePeak(peaks_gr, TxDb = hg38_Annotation))
  peak_list[[(length(peak_list) + 1)]] <- assign(file, annotated_peaks_df)
}
peak_list
```